# How to implement a countdown in milliseconds?

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling almost all day to implement an in-build countdown for functionality I created.

It refers to a search function that is handled by jQuery and ajax.
There is `input` field which allows to type keywords, I applied a timeout on the event that reads from that field, so each character provided by the user is resetting the timeout.

As long as you keep providing keywords it wont fire up ajax request, and when you stop for 2 seconds it automatically conducts that request.

What I want is to display a milisecond countdown that shows how much "time" you got left for the ajax request to proceed.

Since for now its just 2 seconds I would want it to be in that format `0:00`.
Obviously the countdown will reset each time a new character is provided.

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div id="response"></div>
```

and the script

```
var keyupTimeoutID = 0;

$('#search').on('input', function () {
    clearTimeout(keyupTimeoutID);
    keyupTimeoutID = setTimeout(function () {

        var srch = jQuery("#search").val();

        // ajax request
        alert('Handler has performer ajax request based on following keywords: ' + srch);

    }, 2000);
});
```

and the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FJ63A/)

Comment: How about a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `setTimeout` will not suit you because you need to execute some code every time you want to update the display (several times per second) while this method is intended for executing something only once. You could, of course, set a chain of timeouts, each one setting the next, but this would be both cumbersome and unlikely to keep the time accurately.

If you need to execute something at regular intervals (which is the case) you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) instead, like this:

```
<input id="search"> <span id="remainingTimeDisplay"></span>
```

```
function programCountDown(){
    $("#search").keydown(function(){
        counter.reset({
            onFinish : function(){
                alert("Time's up!");
            }
        });
    });
}

var counter = {
    interval : null,
    time : null,
    initialTime : 2000,
    stepTime : 10,
    display : null,

    init : function(){
        this.display = $("#remainingTimeDisplay");
    },

    reset : function(pars){
        this.onFinish = pars.onFinish;
        if(this.interval){
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
        this.time = this.initialTime;
        this._displayTime();
        this._set();
    },

    _set : function(){
        this.interval = setInterval(function(){
            counter.time -= counter.stepTime;
            counter._displayTime();
            if(counter.time <= 0){
                clearInterval(counter.interval);
                if($.isFunction(counter.onFinish)){
                   counter.onFinish();
                }
            }
        }, counter.stepTime)
    },

    _displayTime : function(){
        var digit1 = "" + Math.floor(counter.time / 1000);
        var digit2 = "" + Math.floor((counter.time%1000) / 100);
        var digit3 = "" + Math.floor((counter.time%100) / 10);
        this.display.html(digit1 + "." + digit2 + digit3);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    counter.init();
    programCountDown();
});
```

---

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/B4j6w/)

---

Answer (score 0):

Are  you looking for something like this?

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<div>seconds till submit: <span id="submitTimeout"></span></div>
```

```
$(function() {

    var timeout = 5; // 5 seconds tmeout
    var timeoutHandler = 0;
    var intervalHandler = 0;
    var secondsElapsed = 1;

    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        secondsElapsed = 1;
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
        clearInterval(intervalHandler);

        intervalHandler = setInterval(function() {
            $('#submitTimeout').text(secondsElapsed);
            secondsElapsed ++;            
        }, 1000);

        timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function() {
          clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
          clearInterval(intervalHandler); 
          $('#submitTimeout').text(secondsElapsed);
          secondsElapsed = 1;
          alert('value is submited to the server');
        }, timeout*1000);



    })

});
```

---

[**jsBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/pigiruwi/1/edit)

---

But it does pretty much what you need. You can use `setInterval` function along with `setTimeout`.

Comment: The example is not a countdown. It seems to be counting **up** from 1 to 5 in full seconds and not **down** from 2 to 0 in milliseconds as requested.

Comment: It is very easy to change to count down. My goal was not to write a complete solution for the op, but just to show the direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var countClock = 0;
$(document).on('input', '#search', function() {
    clearInterval(countClock);
    var sec = 3
    countClock = setInterval(function(){
        sec --;
        $("#displayclock").html("0:0" + sec);
        if (sec===0) {
            clearInterval(countClock);
            sec=3;
            var srch = jQuery("#search").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "handler.php",
                data: ({search: srch}),
                success: function(response){
                    $('#response').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    },1000);

});
```